# Number of processes named 'doodle'

Tags: process

I have been using 12.10 for a few days. Just upgraded it from 12.04. My computer, which has a 4GB RAM and 64 bit Intel processor, just goes slow randomly. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and login through a command prompt, I see a number of processes using `ps -A`.

I get many instances of a process named 'doodle' running. So many that I have to `pkill` them by hand.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dennis@lightning:/tmp$ apt-cache search doodle
doodle - Desktop Search Engine (client)
```

Ah. That'll be trying to index your filesystem, which usually slows machines down to a crawl. If you're not using it, remove it :)